# Unexpected behaviour of width property

Tags: html, css

I have three divs in one row, theirs display property is set to table-cell. They are all wrapped by parent div. I need the inner divs to have equal width, so I set it to 33%. But the behaviour of width is strange. If 33% is set, the divs aren't stretched to maximum.But if I set 1%, the all three elements are equal width and stretched to maximum. Why is this such? Have I something wrong in my css?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Ut molestie consequat viverra.</div>
    <div class="child">Pellentesque</div>
    <div class="child">Aliquam lobortis</div>
</div>
.parent {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 25px;
}
.child {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px 10px 5px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:1%;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Seems to work fine on Chrome, Firefox and latest IE with 33%.  What browser are you using?

Comment: its working fine for chrome and firefox...[here is fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: 33% is working fine in fiddle. I think its browser behavior. Test in different browser and make sure.

Comment: I tried it in IE and Firefox. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7TS68/1/

Comment: If you want it to fill 1/3th of the page you must also add "parent{width:100%;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified width for parent div.

Can you specify width as 100% for parent div and check

```
.parent {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 25px;
    width:100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/23JEc/